# Can we get php value dynamically from URL to a batch file?

Tags: php, server, copy, vpn

Here is my batch file script I am running this script via task scheduler
By using the below script I am able to copy all files from invoice_feed folder to Network shared test folder (shared_folder) both servers are connecting via VPN

```
Echo off
net use \\windows_servername\test_folder shared_folder_password /user:shared_folder_username
xcopy C:\Apache\htdocs\Invoices\invoice_feed \\windows_servername\\test_folder
```

If I want to copy a specific file to network shared folder then I am adding manually that file to the above batch script, it is working well. Below is the code

```
Echo off
net use \\windows_servername\test_folder shared_folder_password /user:shared_folder_username
xcopy C:\Apache\htdocs\Invoices\invoice_feed\file_to_copy.csv \\windows_servername\\test_folder
```

Can I run this script by using PHP? If yes then can I pass dynamic value from URL and pass that in place of specific file name like below?

```
xcopy C:\Apache\htdocs\Invoices\invoice_feed\<?php echo $_GET['csv_file_name']?> \\windows_servername\\test_folder
```

Or is there any other way instead of doing this in batch file I mean completely by using php?
I am trying to run the script like below

```
$file_name = $_GET['csv_file_name'];
echo exec('net use \\windows_servername\test_folder shared_folder_password /user:shared_folder_username');
echo exec('xcopy C:\Apache\htdocs\Invoices\invoice_feed\$file_name \\windows_servername\\test_folder');
```

But no luck. It is showing 0 files copied. Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Massively unclear what you are trying to ask. Where is there even _any_ connection whatsoever here between executing this batch script, and PHP? Are you invoking this _via_ PHP somehow? If so, show that part.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: @04FS , I have edited my question and updated my php script. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In batch file you can pass argument and catch that argument.

`batchname.bat arg1 arg2`
inside batch file you can catch argument as below.

```
set arg1=%1
set arg2=%2
xcopy C:\Apache\htdocs\Invoices\invoice_feed\%arg1% \\windows_servername\\test_folder
```

so if you triggering this batch from php, you can easily pass the get parameter as argument to the batch file.

you can run batch file using `system` function.

```
$last_line = system("cmd /c C:/path/to/bat/batchname.bat ".$_GET['csv_file_name'], $ret_val);
echo 'last line: '.$last_line;
echo 'return values: '.$ret_val;
```

Comment: How to pass values to arg1, arg2 by using php? Can you please show me sample code? Above I have updated my question with php script which I am using?

Comment: @jagad89I am getting "The command was successfully completed." on browser. But file was not copied to the network folder.

Comment: Do your file name having any space?

Comment: There is no space in file name.  but when I gave the file name directly on the batch file it is working.

Comment: I have updated answer to see last line output and full batch output. this will help us. temporary you may remove `echo off` from batch file.

Comment: @user3408779 when you run batch manually, are you running it as admin? i have also updated path separator from `\\` to `/` in path

Comment: It is working with exec command. Not system command  like below exec('C:\\scripts\batch1.bat '.$_GET['FILE_NAME']);

Comment: No, I am simply double click on the batch file . Not as admin. But is this exec command will work on Linux machine also ? Currently this is on windows machine

Comment: exec function work fine on linux but your batch file will not work on linux. you will required to create a bash script and it have slightly different syntax to pass argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203244/discussion-between-user3408779-and-jagad89).